# How to uppercase only the letters within a string that also contained numbers?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am running this command in order to uppercase all the letters within a string:

```
capstan_df['DEFAULT QTAG'] = capstan_df['DEFAULT QTAG'].apply(lambda x: str(x).upper())
```

However I am getting NAN back for most of them, this is because most of my QTAGs look like `econ_power_1` which I would like to turn into `ECON_POWER_1`. Will regex solve this?

Comment: `str('econ_power_1').upper()` does give you `ECON_POWER_1`. Are you sure your data don't contain 'nan'?

Comment: can you share sample data?, documentation shows it should not be a problem to have numbers in the string

Comment: No need to `apply - lambda`, just `.str.upper()` the series. Much faster.  And no, the number in the string shouldn't be an issue, I'm guessing the data has NaNs to begin with. Hard to tell though.

Answer (score 0):

What version of pandas are you using?  I'm using 0.23.4, and if I create a dataframe as such:

`x = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['asdf','adsfda-4234','adsfdsaf_12321']})`

...then I can simply use `x['x'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())` and it works fine.  You can also do `str(x).upper()` and that works fine as well.  So, the numbers in the strings are not your issue here.